# Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) on OS X 10.13 keeps wanting me to put .gitignore and .DS_store on the path

Tags: eclipse

I just upgraded to Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) on OS X 10.13.
I have a large existing repository of java projects and I've installed the javascript and GWT plugins for Eclipse.

The problem is this: whenever I do almost anything (ex. save a file I'm working on), I get an error:

`An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Path must include project and resource name: /.gitignore`

specifically, the error comes from jface:

`Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".`

the top of the error code is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /.gitignore
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2128)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFile(Container.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingViewContentProvider.getFile(StagingViewContentProvider.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingEntry.getFile(StagingEntry.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingEntry.getProblemSeverity(StagingEntry.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.ProblemLabelDecorator.decorateImage(ProblemLabelDecorator.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingLabelProvider.java:101)
```

But, there's a .gitignore in both the repo root and the project root and the project path settings are:

```
PARENT_LOC /Users/brian/git/JavaCodeFromSVN
PROJECT_LOC /Users/brian/git/JavaCodeFromSVN/jsAipotu
WORKSPACE_LOC /Users/brian/git/JavaCodeFromSVN
```

So I can't figure out what the problem is or how to fix it.

I can work in eclipse but it's really annoying to get these messages all the time.

I'm sure it's something obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

Might anyone be able to help? It seems that every time I upgrade Eclipse, it's a headache of one kind or another. Perhaps, someday, I'll learn my lesson and not upgrade :(

thanks

Brian

Comment: That message means egit is trying to use the path `/.gitignore` as a resource path, but a resource path must have a project name and a resource name - `/project/name`. I don't use egit so I can't say why it is doing this wrong.

Comment: Does pressing the Refresh button in the Staging view or un-staging of the file help? Otherwise, please tell if and which files are staged and whether you used Git on the command line.

Comment: Howgler - thanks. This is my fault for using git without fully understanding it. I do not use git on the command line - I use the menus in eclipse. In the staging view, I don't see any 'refresh' button but I do see 43 things listed as 'unstaged changes' and some of these are .gitignore and .DS_Store files from some of my projects. Some have > signs near them and others have a blue question mark on the file icon. It looks like I need to read up on egit - but this has never been a problem before - can you recommend a good site?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I may have fixed the problem. Here's what I did that made this go away.

Right-click the project: Team -> advanced -> Clean... and let it clean all it found (lots of .gitignores etc)

At that point, I was getting warnings about .DS_Store pretty consistently.

I followed the directions at https://intellipaat.com/community/9089/how-can-i-remove-dsstore-files-from-a-git-repository-gitignore-dsstore (By Debashis Borgohain)

they are:

1. Remove existing .DS_Store files from the repo. In the top level repo directory:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

2. Create or update the .gitignore file at the top of the repo to contain a listing for .DS_Store. WHen set like this, even if Mac OS re-creates the .DS_Store files, they will be ignored by git when you commit changes, etc. Here is one way:

```
echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
```

3. Commit the revised .gitignore

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m '.DS_Store banished!'
```

to get rid of all the .DS_Store files, tell git to ignore them, and now it seems happy.

Comment: This is, effectively, a [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). Please expand your answer to include as much information here as possible, at least the minimum needed to actually accomplish what you are suggesting, and use the links only for reference. Basically, posts on Stack Overflow (and all of Stack Exchange) must be self-contained. That means that enough information needs to be in your answer such that the reader doesn't *need to* go off-site for directions. Right now, that's not the case for this answer.

Comment: Once you've [edit]ed the additional information into your post (also see the [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)), feel free to raise an "in need of moderator attention" flag to request that your post be evaluated for undeletion.

Comment: “Team -> advanced -> Clean... and let it clean all it found” is very dangerous. It will delete (it did, in my case) all the .project and other project files, which effectively destroys the workspace. Be careful in whatever you delete or make a backup of your workspace before!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I have a Maven project with sub-projects, and I made my Maven (base) project folder **equal to** the workspace folder:

```
 eclipse-workspace = maven base project folder = root of Git repo
 +--  subproject_1
 |    +--  pom.xml (of subproject)
 +--  subproject_2
 |    +--  pom.xml (of subproject)
 +--  pom.xml (of base project)
```

The first error was, that the base project could not be imported as a project. I thought this was meaningless, since the base project doesn’t contain code in my case, it is only a container. However, it seems Eclipse requires the base project to be a folder **in** the workspace:

```
 eclipse-workspace
 +--  project (base project) = root of Git repo
      +--  subproject_1
      |    +--  pom.xml (of subproject)
      +--  subproject_2
      |    +--  pom.xml (of subproject)
      +--  pom.xml (of base project)
```